# C function to remove instances of one char from a string

Tags: string, char

I did it right but it only works if the base string is one word:
#include <stdio.h>

```
void withoutString(char *new, char *base, char removee){
    while(*base){
        if(*base!=removee){
            *new++=*base;}
            base++;
    
    
    }
    *new='\0';
}

int main()
{
    char b[16],n[16],r;
    printf("Please enter string: ");
    scanf(" %s", b);
    printf("Which character do you want to remove? \n");
    scanf(" %c",&r);                       
    withoutString(n, b, r);                       
    printf(" The new string is %s", n);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make it work for more words?

Answer (score 0):

Read and understand the documentation of `scanf`. Good sources for documentation on the C standard functions are the C standard itself and POSIX.

You will then notice that `scanf` is not the best function to read a whole line, so look for `fgets` next.